# How do I create a question where only one choice may be selected without using dropdowns?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am creating a form where I want the user to select ONE choice from several. Let's say (for example) the form asks: Do you like to walk?  Do you like to run?  Do you like to jog?  I want the user to be able to only select one.  Is it possible to do this without using a drop down?  From a design standpoint we want to use checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a question with only one answer in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) and do not want to use a Dropdown, then you should use Radio Buttons instead.  This is the appropriate Choice Type to use when only one answer may be selected.

If you want the ensure the user has intentionally selected an answer, do not specify a default choice and make the question required.  This will force them to select a single answer before submitting the form.